# how to grep for "+" or "-" values?

Tags: bash, grep

I need to grep for values with + or - symbol

```
eg: -3 or +3
```

I tried the following , doesnt help me

```
$ echo $accessTime | grep "^((\+)|(\-))[0-9]+$"

$ echo $accessTime | grep "+[0-9]+"

$ echo $accessTime | grep "\+[0-9]+"

$ echo $accessTime | grep "'+'[0-9]+"

$ echo $accessTime | grep "^'\+'[0-9]+"

$ echo $accessTime | grep "^(\+)[0-9]+"

$ echo $accessTime | grep "^(\+)[0-9]+"
```

Can you guys pls help me ....Im learning bash for past few days only..Thanks

Comment: Basic grep would consider `\+` as qunatifier and `+` as a pattern to match literal `+` symbol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its easier than what you think, you should try

```
echo $accessTime | grep [+-]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
accessTime='+3'
echo "$accessTime" | grep "+[0-9]\+"
+3
```

Quantifier `+` needs to be escaped in normal `grep` and literal `+` must not be escaped.

With `grep -E` it is **exactly reverse**:

```
echo "$accessTime" | grep -E "\+[0-9]+"
+3
```

Quantifier `+` must not be escaped in `grep -E` (extended regex) and literal `+` . needs to be escaped.

Comment: Thanks Anubhava!  I got it right now... Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: You also have accepted an answer that is erroneous due to unquoted variable and grep pattern. That solution will even find `foo-bar` as valid search not just numbers with `+` and `-`.